# how to pass argument to main method in eclipse?

Tags: java, enums, argument-passing

I am trying to pass parameter to a java class main method I want to pass parameter using eclipse so I went to

```
run -> run configuration -> program arguments
```

and I wrote my arguments

```
exp grammar
```

But whenever I run it gives me this error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at LL.main(LL.java:146)
```

Which means it does not see the second argument `"grammar"`, anyone know why and how to solve this ?

---

edit , here is my main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String exp = args[0] + '$';
    LL input = new LL(exp, Grammar.fromFile(args[1]));
    try {
        input.lLParse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Suspended:  That's the main method that's already posted in the question.

Comment: does the program run successfully when you call `java LL exp grammar` from command line?

Comment: it is gives the same error from command line although i am giving input of two strings but the error indicates it sees only one .

Comment: Could you System.out.println() each of your arguments and confirm that they are both being read?

Comment: first argument exp is printed correctly which is args[0] the problem is with the grammar as my main cannot see args[1] although i am passing 2 strings . and by the way i cannot print the grammar

Answer (score 2):

In `Run -> Run Configuration -> Java Application -> Arguments` enter inputs separating by `space`

Comment: that is exactly what i am doing but it cannot see the second argument as it gives me array out of boundary exception

Comment: Halawa, Can you please add screen shot of your arguments window

Answer (score 1):

1)Right-click on Main class

2)Click on 'Run As'

3)Click on 'Run Configurations...'

4)Click on 'Arguments'

5)Enter input in '**Program Arguments**' section

6)Click on 'Apply' and 'Run'

**Note** - for multiple inputs, you can enter multiple inputs in different lines in 'Program argument section'

Answer (score 0):

Check for extra space between this two arguments

Answer (score -1):

"ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

Try extending the index for array exp to args.length

Comment: Sorry didn't see that. try doing this                                                                 for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
            System.out.println(args[i]);
    }